# Find user defined functions and their usage in a massive code base

Tags: php

I'm currently working with an massive PHP codebase, witch is completely undocumented.

Here's the deal. All of the PHP code is included every page call. They build a simple include all kinda function that scan's the directory and includes all PHP files it can find. It works recursively for all the subfolders.

I would like to know what functions are used in what files and from which files those functions came.

I need to know this in order to switch to normale includes. Also it gives me more information about not used functions and files (since it a really old and big codebase, there is a lot of legacy in it).

It there a tool or something for PHP that can check this kind of stuff in a codebase?

Comment: Over 2 weeks and only my answer!  I was hoping someone would arrive with the goods.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans gives me pretty good visibility, for the spot inquiry.  I'm interested to see if you get something with more value as a straight "audit" or inventory tool.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question so you seem to have found a solution. There's a php function: `get_defined_functions()`, `get_defined_vars()`, `get_defined_constants()`. You can use them in a page and you know the functions/vars/constants defined for use but not being used.